# Value_Error: Batch-size is not a legal parameter

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a convolutional neural network to classify the CIFAR10 dataset. The goal is to change various hyper-parameters, in my case the optimizer, learning rate and batch-size. Only varying the optimizer and learning rate works fine, however adding the batch-size throws the Value error quoted in the title. Any help is appreciated:
Below is a part of my code. I hope it's the relevant part, but I'm still learning, so not sure about that.

So far, I tried to change the key in the dict param_grid to 'batchsize' because I thought maybe it's a syntax error. I also checked the internet which parameters are allowed to the function GridSearchCV parameter param_grid, alas I didn't found it.

```
model = KerasClassifier(
build_fn=create_model,
epochs=epochs,
verbose=1)

optimizer_candidates = [Adam, RMSprop]
lr_candidates = [1e-3, 5e-3, 1e-4]
batch_size = [128, 64]


param_grid = {
    "optimizer": optimizer_candidates,
    "lr": lr_candidates,
    "batch-size": batch_size}

grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=model,
    param_grid=param_grid,
    n_jobs=1,
    verbose=1,
    cv=3)

grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the batch size in your `param_grid` should be `"batch_size"`, not `"batch-size"`.

Comment: Thanks, completley ignored that

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be "batch_size" instead of "batch-size".

Comment: Thank you, completley ignored that